# Get current time of day in c++

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

## case

I need to write a program that moves files around at times that are set in a configuration file. The time can be 00:00:01 seconds untill 24:00:00 hours. This is converted into seconds. So if somebody wants to move a file at 12:00:00 pm today, the move time is 12 * 60 * 60 = 43200 seconds. This is done every day and the program needs to check if that time is reached.

I use the [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library to get the time now since epoch in seconds using:

```
auto dayInSeconds = 86400;
auto currentTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock().now().time_since_epoch());
auto timeWithoutDays = currentTime % dayInSeconds;

std::cout << "time in seconds today: " << timeWithoutDays.count() << std::endl;
```

## problem

This shows me the current time since epoch in seconds. But now for example ( 13:45 Amsterdam time) it returns a number of: 42294. If I run it exactly five seconds later in a loop it returns 42299. So the counting seems to be correct. What is not correct, is that 42299 seconds is 1174 hours (42299/ 60 /60). Which should mean that is now 11:somewhat AM but its 13:32 PM. Or not? What am I doing wrong? I just need to know, how many seconds have passed since 00:00:00 this day. So i can check if the user set time is passed and stuff needs to be done.

I would like to keep using the chrono library for all sorts of reasons, but mainly because I understand that one. So if answers use that library, it would be a great help. I have a feeling i'm doing something completely stupid.

## fix

For any other that seeks the same answer. I fixed it like this, it seems to work:

```
auto dayInSeconds = 86400;
auto amsterdamUTCPlusTime = 7200;
auto currentTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock().now().time_since_epoch());
auto timeWithoutDays = currentTime % dayInSeconds;
auto currentTimeInSeconds = timeWithoutDays.count() + amsterdamUTCPlusTime;
std::cout << "time in seconds today: " << currentTimeInSeconds << std::endl;
```

Comment: You correctly deduced that `system_clock` is tracking UTC.  Your fix is fine except that it ignores daylight saving.  For example at 2020-10-25 01:00:00 UTC Amsterdam will change its UTC offset to 3600s.  C++20 will bring better tools for dealing with time zones in C++.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. Forgot about that one... The compiler doesn't handle the c++20 functionality yet. Can't wait for that though. There are so many usefull improvements there!

Comment: There's an open-source preview of C++20 here (https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) if you want to deal with a 3rd party lib.  There's one source that has to be compiled, and depending on platform you may need to download the IANA database (that can also be automated).  Build instructions: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation

Answer (score 2):

C++20 brings extensions to `<chrono>` to deal with timezones.  It isn't shipping yet (to the best of my knowledge).  But here is what it will look like:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    zoned_time zt{"Europe/Amsterdam", floor<seconds>(system_clock::now())};
    auto lt = zt.get_local_time();
    auto tod = lt - floor<days>(lt);
    cout << "time in seconds today: " << tod.count() << '\n';
    cout << hh_mm_ss{tod} << '\n';
}
```

Example output:

```
time in seconds today: 71923
19:58:43
```

If your computer's local time zone setting is already set to "Europe/Amsterdam", then `"Europe/Amsterdam"` above can be replaced with `current_zone()`.

This gets the current time in UTC, truncates it to seconds precision, and then pairs it with the "Europe/Amsterdam" `time_zone` to create a `zoned_time`.  Then the local time is extracted from the `zoned_time`.  The local time of day is simply the local time minus the beginning of that day (`floor<days>(lt)`).  This is stored in `tod` which has type `seconds`.  Wrapping it in a `hh_mm_ss` prints it out in a hh:mm:ss format.

There exists a [free, open-source C++20 `<chrono>` preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which can be used with C++11/14/17 to do this.  To use it, it must be [installed](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).  There's a single source file to be compiled, tz.cpp, and it needs to have access to the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which can be automatically downloaded with specific build settings.

The source code above must be trivially modified by adding `#include "date/tz.h"` and `using namespace date;`.  In C++11 and 14, change `zoned_time` to `zoned_seconds`, and `hh_mm_ss` to `hh_mm_ss<seconds>`.

Another possibility is to build your own UTC offset calculator for just Amsterdam (assuming current rules).  The advantage of this is that it can use of subset of the [free, open-source C++20 `<chrono>` preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which is header-only, and thus requires no installation, and does not need the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).  That could like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto AmsterdamOffset = [](system_clock::time_point tp)
        {
            auto const y = year_month_day{floor<days>(tp)}.year();
            auto const start = sys_days{Sunday[last]/March/y} + 1h;
            auto const end = sys_days{Sunday[last]/October/y} + 1h;
            if (start <= tp && tp < end)
                return 2h;
            return 1h;
        };

    auto now = floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
    auto local_now = now + AmsterdamOffset(now);
    auto tod = local_now - floor<days>(local_now);
    cout << "time in seconds today: " << tod.count() << '\n';
    cout << hh_mm_ss{tod} << '\n';
}
```

This program hardcodes the fact that Amsterdam daylight saving begins on the last Sunday of March at 01:00:00 UTC and ends on the last Sunday of October at 01:00:00 UTC.

After that, the program logic is much like the C++20 solution shown above.  In C++11, `1h` and `2h` will have to be changed to `hours{1}` and `hours{2}` respectively.

### And yet another approach: Posix time zones

There is also a [Posix time zone library at this link](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) in ptz.h.  This is also a header-only library, so no install issues.  It allows you to use the C++20 `zoned_time` combined with [Posix time zones](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).  This will give you the same results as the example above with the "hard coded" rules for Amsterdam (which are valid back through 1978).

```
#include "date/ptz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    // Amsterdam rules
    Posix::time_zone tz{"CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3"};
    zoned_time zt{tz, floor<seconds>(system_clock::now())};
    auto lt = zt.get_local_time();
    auto tod = lt - floor<days>(lt);
    cout << "time in seconds today: " << tod.count() << '\n';
    cout << hh_mm_ss{tod} << '\n';
}
```

The above assumes C++17.  If in C++11 or 14 the syntax becomes a little messier:

```
zoned_time<seconds, Posix::time_zone> zt{tz, floor<seconds>(system_clock::now())};
```

The `Posix::time_zone` is not part of the C++20 `<chrono>` library, but is compatible with it. It can be used with the C++20 `std::chrono::zoned_time` class template as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use localtime function and get the current time from system.

```
 int getIntTime()
 {
  struct timeb now;
  struct tm *curtime;
  curtime = localtime(&now);
  return(curtime->tm_hour * 10000L + curtime->tm_min * 100L + curtime->tm_sec);
 }
```

And also you should convert the set time  in confgi file to same as output of this  function and compare them as follow:

```
if(getIntTime()  >= converted_time_configfile )
{
   //do processing
}
```